# Pass Multiple parameters Angularjs resource

Tags: php, angularjs, slim, angularjs-resource

I have **UsersService.js**

```
app.factory('UsersService', function($resource) {
return $resource('api/users/:id', {}, {
    update: {method:'PUT'},
});
```

Along with **Index.php** (API with PHP Slim Framework)

```
...
$app->get('/users/:id', 'getUser');
$app->get('/users/:username', 'getUserByUsername');
function getUser(){ ... }
function getUserByUsername(){ ... }
...
```

Now, when I try to call somewhere `UsersService.get({id:15});` It works, but when I try to call `UsersService.get({username:'test'});` It doesn't work...

I tried every possible way I could find on Google but I couldn't make it work. I can make a separate service to get user by username, but I'd like to keep all that in one service if is possible.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell angular $resource from where get value for :username.

For more details look at [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Change yout **UserService.js** :

```
app.factory('UsersService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/users/:id/:username', {id:'@id',username:'@username'}, {
    update: {method:'PUT'}
});
```

Edit:

How does your php script know that when it gets `/users/123` it should run first route, but when it gets `/users/123joe` it should run next route? Do you validate it somehow? If no, you should change your routes in php script, to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I figured out that it's impossible to have two same routes (even if they have different parameters added :id/:username because that apparently doesn't matter), so I added `"getUserByUsername": {method:'GET', url:'api/userByUsername/:username'},` in UsersService.js and in php I added `$app->get('/userByUsername/:username', 'getUserByUsername');` and now it works how I wanted.